# Sql query not return data

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, ms-access-2016, recordset

I use this code for choose code number a procdut in VBA Access and test for found duplicate save product.

```
Dim db as dao.database
Dim rs as dao.recordset

Set db = currentdb

Sql_string = "SELECT code_number FROM table_product WHERE name_product ='Printer HP Color Laser Jet 550dn'"

Set rs = db.openrecordset(Sql_string)

If rs.recordcount > 1 then 
    Msgbox "Duplicate Product"
    db.close
    rs.close 'all seted to nothings
    Exit sub
Else:Text1.value =rs!code_number
End if
```

This code does not work to identify the repeat product name.

Although the product is repeated several times, it always returns the value of one, I check it for different product name but not detect repeat product name.

The following code works fine with a lot of similarity to the above code:

```
Dim db as dao.database
Dim rs as dao.recordset

Set db = currentdb

Sql_string = "SELECT product_name FROM table_product WHERE code_number ='INK001'"

Set rs = db.openrecordset(Sql_string)

If rs.recordcount > 1 then 
    Msgbox "Duplicate Product"
    db.close
    rs.close
    Exit sub
Else:Text2.value =rs!product_name
End if
```

I use Access 2016. Does anyone know what the problem is? Please guide me.
I'm totally confused.

Check table structure and field name .
Check in any database file with this code .
Check sql_string in query work correctly but vba not work correctly.
Ommm repaire office .
Read dao documents.
No result.

Comment: Sure the device name is correct? Might be `Laser Jet 5550dn` instead (at least Google suggests so)? What happens if you create a Query with that SQL statement?

Comment: yes i have considered empty space, The number of duplicate records is displayed in the query, but not in the code.

Comment: The same code still works correctly (second code) but the code in question does not work. (First code)

Comment: In the table, the problem was solved by specifying both fields as an index. I don't know the exact reason, there is a need to read more about DAO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Dim db As dao.database
Dim rs As dao.recordset

Set db = currentdb

Sql_string = "SELECT code_number FROM table_product WHERE name_product = 'Printer HP Color Laser Jet 550dn'"

Set rs = db.openrecordset(Sql_string)

If rs.recordcount > 0 then 
    Msgbox "Duplicate Product"
Else
    Me!Text1.value = rs!code_number
End if
rs.close
```

Or use `DLookup` to reduce to a bare minimum.

Comment: Might be a good idea but I don't understand the reason for this problem

Comment: Check it out. I'm not sure about your definition of duplicates.

Comment: You answered indirectly. In the table I used, I did not define the index field. The problem was solved by specifying both fields. I don't know the exact reason, there is a need to read more. tnx boy

Answer (score 0):

In the table, the problem was solved by specifying both fields as an index. I don't know the exact reason, there is a need to read more about DAO.

Comment: for reasons of performance, the reocrdcount is going to be how many "move next" you done into the data. So, either use a count(*), or use a movelast before you test the count, or you can specify as table type in the openRecordSet. probably better is to just use dcount() and there is no difference in performance.